# Getting GPS Co-Ordinates Programmatically from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, gps

I am new to this forum, however I have found help here many times before, so I am hoping the same happens this time :)

What I would like to do is run a Google Map application on a mobile phone, run the "My Location" feature and get the GPS Co-Ordinates. I would like to do this programmatically.

I could use the built in GPS device, however, in most cases it's about inaccurate by about 20m, which is a bit too much for me. On the other hand, the My Location feature is usually off by a couple of meters (usually less than 5m) which in my case will be enough.

The problem is that I have been looking on the web to see if this can be done. So far, the only way, it seems, that I managed to find to get GPS coordinates from Google Maps is to use some sort of JSP snippet manually.

So basically my question is: Can this be done, and if yes how?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if this cannot be done but someone knows a method that leads to the same results, then please, do let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html) doesn't provide access to your current location (or an estimate of that location).  The *My Location* functionality at maps.google.com uses the [Google Gears GeoLocation API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html#position) to determine the users location.  According to the Gears API reference:

> The Geolocation API provides the best
>   estimate of the user's position using
>   a number of sources (called location
>   providers). These providers may be
>   onboard (GPS for example) or
>   server-based (a network location
>   provider).

I am not sure if Gears works in the browser for your mobile platform. I am assuming it does if the *My Location* functionality on maps.google.com works.

Comment: I don't want to use the application in a browser. I just want to use it as a simple java application that runs on a mobile platform.

I will give a look at the Google Gears API, thanks loads :)

Comment: The answer to your question is "no, you can't get GPS coordinates from Google Maps".  You can do what they do (talk to Gears), but only if you are in a browser (it's a browser plugin).  Which platform are you on?

Comment: I think I might have found some sort of work around, I haven't really tried. I don't want to make a browser application, how ever, it seems that Google gears is supported on my platform. 
How ever, I would like to make a platform independent (As much as possible at least) application, so Google Gears isn't exactly on top of my list either.